# How is plant based chicken and bacon made using soya and pea protein?

Tags: food-science, vegan

I have recently applied for a role at a company which makes vegan meat substitutes (specifically chicken and bacon) and I was wondering how products such as these would be made from soy and pea protein.

Would anyone be able to explain the key steps in the manufacturing process of these?

Answer (score 1):

Those are probably trade secrets (beyond meat ans others...)

There are many recipes/youtube videos out there showing how to make it at home.

I assume industrial plant based meat producers are doing the same but optimized for high yield (and consistency)

for example, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhuQbakN8iI) one show how to make "chicken"